# Spring 4.1.0 RestTemplate POST call

Tags: spring, rest

I am trying to make a rest call using spring 4.1.0 RestTemplate but i dont see HttpEntity class.

```
     HttpHeaders requestHeaders=new HttpHeaders();
     requestHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
     String str = new String();
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity=new HttpEntity<String>(str,requestHeaders);
        RestTemplate restTemplate=new RestTemplate();
        URI location = restTemplate.postForLocation("http://example.com", requestEntity);
```

So there are 2 questions:

> 1. How can i get access to HttpEntity class as its not found?
> 2. how can i get the body or the response from URI?

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
            parts.add("fileType", type.toString());
            parts.add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            parts.add("file", new FileSystemResource(file));
            Response response = restTemplate.postForObject(appUrl , parts, Response.class);

start with response String
restTemplate.postForObject(appUrl , parts, String.class);
```

Comment: Do you know why the HttpEntity class is not available?

Comment: No , try to see if you can get String and then change it

Comment: Due to some ENV issue i was not able to get HttpEntity class, i tried today and am able to see the class. I have body contents that i want to pass, how can i pass them in postForObject? also the @FormParam am using in JAX-RS should automatically map the fields correspondingly which i dont think is possible by MultiValueMap, kindly suggest